# I can't make the background-image work in Xcode in a UIWebview

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

From what I can tell, everything is correct... I have an html file called index.html, and a css file that has the background image reference.

It works if I just load the page on a computer, but no matter what I try to put in the css as the background image for index.html, I can't get it to show anything.

I even tried just putting css in the actual index.html file.

```
 <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url('/images/warning_small.png');
            background-repeat:repeat;
        }
    </style>
```

Is there something I don't know about UIWebviews? Does it not like certain images or something?

Comment: Do you have the HTML embedded in the app ?

Comment: Yes, in the same resource as the image and the css

Comment: Is the path the right one?

Answer (score 1):

There is simple trick to follow, it will definitely work. Follow the simple steps..

1. Create a folder in your project folder system.
2. Put all the html and resources files in the folder.
3. Remove unlinked entries from project.
4. Then add the folder by check the option shown in the image below

[image]

The above step should create a **blue folder** uncommon than other folder.

The blue folder is the trick, when you will run the app in your app folder you will be able to see an extra folder which you added at step 4. Now since all you resource files are in the folder the html file will look for the resources in the folder itself, and it should work.

You might need to tweak the path in the html, but this should work. It works for me always.

Cheers.

Comment: I've already been using the blue folders.

I actually moved the image into the same folder as the html, and changed the css to reference it there, and it worked... but this same problem is happening with other images, and moving it to the same folder is NOT working for those images.

Comment: Can you try open the `html` in the browser from the Application Folder and see whether its opening correctly or, not.